# Android add to a users stared locations (Google maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have been using google maps in my application for some time. The application allows users to write a review for somewhere they have visited. They can add a location to the review, and view the place the wrote their review as an overlay showing the other reviews in the area.

I want to allow a user to syncronise with their google account and add the saved locations as stars to their map. I have seen a few applications which allow this, but have been looking and can't find any information at all on how to do this, can anyone point out some guides?

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific about what you are referring to as 'google maps.' Are you talking about the Android Google Maps SDK or the Google Maps APIs? Where are the reviews persisted? Can you persist the 'starred' attribute in the same location? If not, perhaps you need an app in the cloud to store associations between users and the review/location data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)?

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you would like to allow the users to write review. And if you want to do this so using Google there is **Places API** available as answered by Age but right now Google Places API does not allow to write review. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329048/google-places-api-submitting-reviews). You can get the overall review rating from the API like 3.5 or 4 like something.

**Rating contains the Place's rating, from 0.0 to 5.0, based on user reviews.**

But you can use other API which is very useful to your requirement is [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/).

Resource for foursquare [tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-use-foursquare-api-on-android-application/).

Hope this will help you..