# Add user review to Google map from my application(Android)

Tags: google-places-api, android, location-based-service

I am trying to create a location-based services Android application. I had successfully getting the user reviews from Google Places API by following the guidance from this link.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

I also found many posts regarding how to get user reviews from Google Places. But Now I want to create a function which user can insert reviews from my application. Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: a bit old, but seems like exactly the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329048/google-places-api-submitting-reviews

Comment: @ılǝ: Ya. I read this before I post. But it is 2 years ago. So I thought there will be some new updates after that.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no API for writing review. Also the Google+ mobile URL doesn't have the write review option from last year. Its a bug , but Google is not fixing this.

There is only one way to write review is through desktop URL. I have a similar location base app in play store where I have done some workaround to show desktop site to write review.

Comment: A bug is a malfunction, not a missing feature. And what do you mean by "desktop site"?

Comment: if i understand currectly you open a url on browser. if it is can you tell me how?